# Testing process and expectation with weka for data that exist in my sql

Tags: java, mysql, weka

I have training data set that exists in arff file and I have testing data set that exists in mysql data base (1) and I have another data (2) also exists in mysql 
How can I do the Testing process in java with weka on data base (1) and then How can I do the expectation from data base (2) according to the testing process result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- first [setup your mysql connection](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Databases) (dont't forget to add it to classpath or import).
- then [create your arff loader and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114357/convert-data-input-in-weka-from-arff-to-mysql) (you could re-use most of this code).
- if you use nominal or string, be careful to re-use the instances created during training because the mapping (string/nominal to binary) could mismatch otherwise. For this, when creating instances for testing, just do:  myTestingInstances = New Instances(myTestingInstances)